# Assigning default table properties to tables created by a crawler

Tags: amazon-web-services

I'm trying to assign table properties to the tables that are created with a crawler.

The idea is to have all of the tables that are created with a crawler have the same default properties (plus the ones they'd usually have).

I examined the options in the crawler creation interface but didn't see such an option.
Creating a python boto3 script to alter table property values after the table creation is the only thing that comes to mind.

If this is not possible with the default crawler functionality, what is a viable approach to attach table properties to every table that is created with a certain crawler?

EDIT: One possible solution would be to create a lambda function that checks if the custom parameters exist on the glue tables and if not creates them.

Comment: you are talking about Glue Crawlers correct, I usually create the table before the crawler runs!

Comment: @BaluVyamajala Creating tables with those properties would be one approach, yes. The problem is I want to set those default properties to already existing tables (most of them are updated with a crawler)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option 1**

Directly adding the fields in the definition might be the best way in approaching this (using CloudFormation).

https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-glue-classifier-csvclassifier.html

**Option 2**

I guess there's some reason why you do not add the table fields directly. If this should be triggered by the data itself the clean way you might want to look into is writing custom classifiers:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/custom-classifier.html

**Option 3**

When you need a quick hack you could merge the schema by crawling an additional file with the schema info that's missing and let the crawler merge the fields:
If you have JSON S3 files for example (or any consistent format for your use case) you can add an additional ***init*** file and add the columns there. Set

```
{
   "Version": 1.0,
   "Grouping": {
      "TableGroupingPolicy": "CombineCompatibleSchemas" }
}
```

Cite from AWS doc:

"To help illustrate this option, suppose that you define a crawler with an include path s3://bucket/table1/. When the crawler runs, it finds two JSON files with the following characteristics:

File 1 – S3://bucket/table1/year=2017/data1.json

- File content – {“A”: 1, “B”: 2}
- Schema – A:int, B:int

File 2 – S3://bucket/table1/year=2018/data2.json

- File content – {“C”: 3, “D”: 4}
- Schema – C: int, D: int

By default, the crawler creates two tables, named year_2017 and year_2018 because the schemas are not sufficiently similar. However, if the option Create a single schema for each S3 path is selected, and if the data is compatible, the crawler creates one table. The table has the schema

A:int,B:int,C:int,D:int and partitionKey year:string.

See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/crawler-configuration.html

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. Could you expand on option 1? I've read the linked documentation - if I understand correctly, I can update my existing tables at once with a single cloudformation template. Any sort of advice to point me in the right direction would be appreciated.